# Clojure getting highest value from zipmap

Tags: clojure

So I've got my proposed zip map here and it works perfectly. As you can see I've got the data loading.

That is what it looks like in the repl which is perfect.
And right here is the map

```
:Year 2020, :Day 27, :January 59, :February 38
:Year 2020, :Day 28, :January 41, :February 57
:Year 2020, :Day 29, :January 56, :February 51
:Year 2020, :Day 31, :January 94, :February -999
:Year 2020, :Day 30, :January 76, :February -999 

(map [:Day :Month
```

Bear in mind this is just a snippet of the code I've done. How would you propose I find the highest value day in January? And by highest I mean by the number next to the months

```
(into(sorted-map-by >(fn [:January]))Ha)
```

I tried this to no success, The "Ha" at the end is just the name of the function where I am initialising the zipmap and using io/reader to read the file

Comment: Easier if you don't use `zipmap`.  Take cols 0,1,2, find max in col 2, then extract day. Repeat for cols 0,1,3 (feb). etc.

Comment: Any reason why a zipmap is more difficult ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [max-key](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/max-key) and [reduce](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce):

```
(def data [{:Year 2020, :Day 27, :January 59, :February 38}
           {:Year 2020, :Day 28, :January 41, :February 57}
           {:Year 2020, :Day 29, :January 56, :February 51}
           {:Year 2020, :Day 31, :January 94, :February -999}
           {:Year 2020, :Day 30, :January 76, :February -999}])

(reduce (partial max-key :January) data)
;; => {:Year 2020, :Day 31, :January 94, :February -999}

(:Day (reduce (partial max-key :January) data))
;; => 31
```

Comment: Could you give me a little explanation as to what both functions are doing, I don't want to take on board something I don't understand although it is an extremely good answer :)

Comment: Both functions are fairly easy to understand. Use the links in my answer to access the documentation, read what they do, and try them out yourself in the REPL. I should mention that `reduce` is very practical for processing sequences. Essentially `(reduce f [1 2 3 4])` evaluates to `(f (f (f 1 2) 3) 4)`.

Comment: Will do Thankyou :)

Comment: Good call - I've never used `max-key` before. Although, I would have chosen `apply` instead of `reduce`.

Comment: @AlanThompson, you're correct: no need to bother with reduce + partial , when you can simple do `(apply max-key :January data)`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how your exact datastructure looks like, but assuming it's a vector of maps you can do something like this:

```clj
(def data
  [{:Year 2020, :Day 27, :January 59, :February 38}
   {:Year 2020, :Day 28, :January 41, :February 57}
   {:Year 2020, :Day 29, :January 56, :February 51}
   {:Year 2020, :Day 31, :January 94, :February -999}
   {:Year 2020, :Day 30, :January 76, :February -999}])

(->> data
     (sort-by :January)
     last
     :January)
;; => 94
```

Sorting the vector by using a keyword as a function to look up its value in the map, then taking the vector with the highest value for January, then get the value belonging to the key `:January` from that vector. Let me know if your data structure looks a bit different.

Comment: Yes my data structure is exactly like that but in the file I am loading it from, Just another quick question, How would you also return the year and the day that the highest January is from? I tried to upvote your answer but my account is fairly new so it wont allow me :/

Comment: @Codemosh You can select multiple keys with for example [`juxt`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/juxt), applying multiple functions (the keywords) you want to the result. Using the same `max-key` approach as above (`apply max-key f` is basically the same  as `->> sort-by f last` only probably a bit better performance) you get `((juxt :Year :Day :January :February) (apply max-key :January m)) ;; => [2020 31 94 -999]`.

Comment: @Codemosh Or you can use a `let` binding and [destructure the keys](https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring#_associative_destructuring) like so `(let [{:keys [Year Day January February]} (apply max-key :January m)] [Year Day January February]) ;; => [2020 31 94 -999]`.

Answer (score 1):

@Rulle's answer is very good.
Without `max-key` it would be:

```
(def data [{:Year 2020, :Day 27, :January 59, :February 38}
           {:Year 2020, :Day 28, :January 41, :February 57}
           {:Year 2020, :Day 29, :January 56, :February 51}
           {:Year 2020, :Day 31, :January 94, :February -999}
           {:Year 2020, :Day 30, :January 76, :February -999}])

(defn seq-max [seq greater key]
  (reduce (fn [a b] (if (greater (key a) (key b)) a b)) seq))
;; if no key is wanted, choose the function `identity` as key!
;; e.g.
;; (seq-max (map :January data) > identity)
;; => 94

(:Day (seq-max data > :January)) ;; => 31
```